# "_auth.default.auth" is not a function react-native

Tags: firebase, visual-studio-code, react-native

i have installed latest version of react-native and firebase. when im trying to call "firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)" its getting an error and its saying "_auth.default.auth is not a function"

in root folder files not getting this kind of error. its working. but im getting inside folder file and call fire base function this error will occur.

Root folder file App.js

"firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)"

Working..

./src/component/LoginForm.js

"firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)"

not working. getting above error.

------------------App.js Root level (working code with "`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)`" )-------------------

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Header, Button, Spinner } from './components/common';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import firebase from '@firebase/app';

class App extends Component {
  state = { loggedIn: false };

  componentWillMount() {

    var config = {
      apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-MY',
      authDomain: 'xxxx-a115e.firebaseapp.com',
      databaseURL: 'https://xxxx-xxxx.firebaseio.com',
      projectId: 'xxx-xx',
      storageBucket: 'xxxx-a115e.appspot.com',
      messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxx'
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if(user) {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
      }else {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: false });
      }
    }); 

   }
```

-------------/src/components/LoginForm.js file not working (`firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword`)---------------

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { firebase } from '@firebase/auth';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Card, CardSection, Input, Spinner } from './common';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    state = { email: '', password: '', error: '', loading: false };

    onButtonPress() {
        const { email, password } = this.state;

        //var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        this.setState({ error: '', loading: true});

        firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(this.onLoginSucess.bind(this))
            .catch( () => {
                firebase.auth().createUserAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .then(this.onLoginSucess.bind(this))
                    .catch(this.onLoginFail.bind(this));
            });
    }
```

i identified this happening because of file is not in root level of project files structure. help me to get solution for this..

Comment: which library are you using for Firebase?

Comment: npm install firebase --save and npm install firebase-admin --save both i installed.. current available version.. latest

Comment: this happening on Android Emulator..

Answer (score 4):

New firebase API have to use import like this for Auth.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
```

I am using firebase version 5.11.0. hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Spent a day on this, and this is the only thing I could get to work for me.

Worked through about 8 different tutorials, and not a single one worked. Finally combined some things from a couple of tutorials and StackOverflow and it started working:

```
import {  getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
const auth = getAuth();
```